# Flow tests using safe acids and bases and an indicator

Tags: acid-base

I want to conduct some visualization tests on a new mixing device.  I would like to mix acid with base and use an indicator to see a color change.  These are flow tests and the flow rates of acid and base will be equal.  I'd like to only use a stoichiometric excess of 20% of either the acid or base.

Since I will be conducting these experiments in my basement, I'm thinking I should probably try to use acids and bases that are safe to humans.  I suppose I could use a 0.001M concentration of HCL and NaOH.  But I'd be handling more concentrated solutions prior to dilution to these concentrations.

I could maybe use something like baking soda for the "base" and vinegar for the "acid".  Since these are weak, there will be equilibrium shifts during the reactions in order to use up all of either the acid or base (depending upon which reactant is the 20% excess).  I need the reaction to be very rapid such that the several microsecond mixing that I am expecting will be rate controlling.

Any suggestions for acids/bases and indicator that I might use?  A strongly colored indicator in the weak acid or base would be strongly preferred. It would be best if after reaction, that indicator was colorless or an opposite color prior to reaction (red or blue converting to yellow). Again, please note that the flowrate of acid will be identical to that of base (around 0.2 gpm) except that either the acid or base will have a molarity that is 20% higher than the other reactant.

Thanks.

Comment: Baking soda is not a good choice because you will get carbon dioxide gas released, so bubbles could be a problem. Phenolphthalein, like @MaxW suggested in your previous question, is a good indicator choice. Nothing wrong with NaOH as the base.

Comment: @Ed V   Yes, I forgot about the carbon dioxide production.  What about this idea.  I will use water as one of the "reactants" with neutral red indicator in the water.  Neutral red is red at pH below 6.8 and yellow at a pH above 8.0.  Hopefully, the color would be red in water and if not, I'd only need to add a few drops of vinegar, probably.  Then I thought I could react this with baking soda water to get it to turn yellow.  But your point about baking soda is a good one.  So I guess I could use a dilute solution of NaOH even down to .0001M to turn the indicator to yellow.

Comment: Definitely give it a try! I suggest trying several concentrations of NaOH solution. If 0.1 mM NaOH works well, then try 1 mM. If no change, the go back to the more dilute solution. If there is a change, then try 10 mM. You want a fast reaction and that favors higher concentrations: this chemistry is all about favorable encounters at the ion/molecular level!

Comment: Here's what I'm planning to do.  I'm going to use sodium carbonate as my base with a pH close to 12.  Water with red cabbage indicator will be the other reactant.  The blue color in the water/red cabbage solution should turn yellow when mixed with sodium carbonate.

Comment: Since I'm using water as the "acid", carbon dioxide shouldn't form at a pH that will probably be 9 or higher.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use plain water and water colored with food coloring?